# using init in php (not related to zend)

Tags: php, init

I have a question regarding the practices of using init. If I have a parent class with multiple child classes and they all have the same content inside their init functions would it be best to place that content in the parent init class and then simply do:

```
public function init(){
    parent::init();
}
```

this would seem logical but every where I read, which is unfortunately zend specific, they say to leave the init method in the parent class empty to avoid complexity.

can some one clarify please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait, what? If the parent class needs an `init` method, and the children need the exact same method... just add it to the parent class and do nothing with the children, since they'll inherit it automatically.

This:

```
public function init(){
    parent::init();
}
```

is much better written as:

(Yes, that's *nothing*. If all the method does is call the parent method, just leave it out.)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you will see is just differences in coding practice.

If all child classes have the same exact `init()` method, there is no reason to even have the method declared within the child classes.

In some cases, however I have seen developers do exactly what you have shown. In a lot of cases this may because the eventual intent may be to somehow augment the parent method behavior in a way specific to the class. In other cases, I have seen some collection of children classes override the functionality, so the developer puts a method like this in all child classes just so the intent (execute parent method as is for this child class) is clear to other developers.

Answer (score 0):

if you child class extends parent class and NOT override parents' method then child class simply inherits parents method. Zend got nothing to do with it.

Example

```
class A {
   function foo() {
     echo "foo";
   }
}

class B extends A {}

$b = new B();

$b->foo();
```

the output is

```
foo
```

Moreover `init` is not [any magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). It is just same method as `foo` is. The fact it is used in Zend comes from its design. It could be named `initialize` or `foo` (however, of course, `init` is better choice than `foo` for the purpose of this method within ZF).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of Zend classes have constructors which call those `init()` functions at the end of their constructors.  The idea (I assume) is that classes which inherit from them can avoid calling

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    //child class logic
}
```

IMO this is a unneeded convenience.

Anyway, the only reason you would want to call `parent::init()` in a subclass would be if it was really a Zend grandchild class, and its parent also had some logic in its `init()`.  In those cases, an empty function should call its parent, or be removed entirely.